# Footnote including \tabularx results vertically wrong alignment of footnote number

Tags: vertical-alignment, footnotes, tabularx

Using the \tabularx inside a footnote with the code:

```
\footnote{\label{statistik1}\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth-3em}{lrrrr}
\noindent
Jahr~& Eheschließungen~& Ehescheidungen~& Geburten~& Gestorbene \\
\hline
1964~& 506~182~& 55~698~& 1~065~437~& 644~128 \\
1965~& 492~128~& 58~718~& 1~044~328~& 677~628 \\
1966~& 484~562~& 58~730~& 1~050~345~& 686~321 \\
1967~& 483~101~& 62~835~& 1~019~459~& 687~349 \\
1968~& 444~150~& 65~264~ & ~969~825~& 734~048 \\
1969~& 446~586~& 72~300~ & ~903~456~& 744~360 \\
1970~& 444~510~& 76~520~ & ~810~808~& 734~843 \\
1971~& 432~030~& 80~444~ & ~778~526~& 730~670 \\
1972~& 415~132~& 86~614~ & ~701~214~& 731~264 \\
1973~& 394~544~& 90~164~ & ~635~634~& 731~032 \\
1974~& 377~265~& 98~584~ & ~626~373~& 727~511 \\
1975~& 386~681~& 106~829~ & ~600~512~& 749~260 \\
1976~& 365~728~& 108~258~ & ~602~851~& 733~140 \\
1977~& 358~487~& 74~658*~& ~582~344~& 704~922 \\
1978~& 328~215~& 32~462~ ~& 576~468~& 723~218 \\
1979~& 344~823~& 79~490~ ~& 581~984~& 711~732 \\
1980~& 362~408~& 96~222~ ~& 620~657~& 714~117 \\
1981~& 359~658~& 109~528~ ~& 624~557~& 722~192 \\
\multicolumn{5}{X}{*1977--1978: Zahlensprung aufgrund des Gesetzes zur Reform des Ehe- und Familienrechts vom 14.6.1976.}
~\end{tabularx}
~}
```

the following results: 
[image]
How to get the number up where it belongs?

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth-3em}[t]{lrrrr}` is what you want

Comment: Personally I'd avoid tables in footnotes. And the footnote to a table in a footnote is something that makes me quiver. Either the table is important and so go in the main text, or it's irrelevant and should go nowhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to top-align the table with help of the `[t]` parameter.

Here is, how I would have done this:

```
% arara: pdflatex    

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fnpct}
\usepackage{booktabs,threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\tnote

\begin{document}
    Lorem Ipsum%
    \setcounter{footnote}{21}%
    \footnote{\label{statistik1}% % why a label without a caption?
        \begin{threeparttable}
        \begin{tabular}[t]{%
                S[table-format=4.0]
                S[table-format=6.0]
                S[table-align-text-post = false, table-format=6.0]
                S[table-format=7.0]
                S[table-format=6.0]}
        {Jahr} & {Eheschließungen} & {Ehescheidungen} & {Geburten} & {Gestorbene} \\
        \midrule
        1964& 506182& 55698& 1065437& 644128 \\
        1965& 492128& 58718& 1044328& 677628 \\
        1966& 484562& 58730& 1050345& 686321 \\
        1967& 483101& 62835& 1019459& 687349 \\
        1968& 444150& 65264 & 969825& 734048 \\
        1969& 446586& 72300 & 903456& 744360 \\
        1970& 444510& 76520 & 810808& 734843 \\
        1971& 432030& 80444 & 778526& 730670 \\
        1972& 415132& 86614 & 701214& 731264 \\
        1973& 394544& 90164 & 635634& 731032 \\
        1974& 377265& 98584 & 626373& 727511 \\
        1975& 386681& 106829 & 600512& 749260 \\
        1976& 365728& 108258 & 602851& 733140 \\
        1977& 358487& 74658\tnote{*} & 582344& 704922 \\
        1978& 328215& 32462 & 576468& 723218 \\
        1979& 344823& 79490 & 581984& 711732 \\
        1980& 362408& 96222 & 620657& 714117 \\
        1981& 359658& 109528 & 624557& 722192       
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tablenotes}
            \item[*] 1977-1978: Zahlensprung aufgrund des Gesetzes zur Reform des Ehe- und Familienrechts vom 14.6.1976.
        \end{tablenotes}
        \end{threeparttable}}.
\end{document}
```

[image]